# How to use Moq to unit test a delete operation in entity framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

***Update Edit - Partial Solution - Help still needed *** - I found that the exception was just misleading. It was giving me this exception as I had got the number of times the mocked property was called wrong. It should have been called twice, instead of once. That part works now.

**But I still do not understand why the entity is not being removed from the list. Is it because it is queryable?**

**Original Question Below**

I have been trying to follow [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn314429.aspx) to learn how to unit Entity
Framework 6 and 6.1.

However it does not show **how to unit test a delete operation**. Here is the
code I am trying to test:

```
public void DeleteRequirement(int id)
{
    Requirement requirementToDelete = GetRequirement(id);
    context.Requirement.Remove(requirementToDelete);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

public Requirement GetRequirement(int id)
{
    return (from result in context.Requirement
            where result.Id == id
            select result).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

My unit test code is

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeleteRequirementSuccessfully()
{
    var requirements = new List<Requirement>
    {
        new Requirement {
            Id = 1,
            Title = "Requirement 1",
            Description = "Requirement 1 description"
        },
        new Requirement {
            Id = 2,
            Title = "Requirement 2",
            Description = "Requirement 2 description"
        },
        new Requirement {
            Id = 3,
            Title = "Requirement 3",
            Description = "Requirement 3 description"
        }
    }
    .AsQueryable();

    var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Requirement>>();
    var context = new Mock<RequirementsDatabaseEntities>();

    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Requirement>>()
             .Setup(x => x.Provider)
             .Returns(requirements.Provider);
    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Requirement>>()
             .Setup(x => x.ElementType)
             .Returns(requirements.ElementType);
    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Requirement>>()
             .Setup(x => x.Expression)
             .Returns(requirements.Expression);
    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Requirement>>()
             .Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator())
             .Returns(requirements.GetEnumerator());

    context.Setup(x => x.Requirement).Returns(mockDbSet.Object);

    var dataAccess = new RequirementsDataAccess(context.Object);
    int idToDelete = 1;
    dataAccess.DeleteRequirement(idToDelete);

    context.VerifyGet(x => x.Requirement, Times.Exactly(2)); // <- now verification is correct
    mockDbSet.Verify(x => x.Remove(It.IsAny<Requirement>()), Times.Once());
    context.Verify(x => x.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());
}
```

The test fails on the context.VerifyGet statement with the following error

```
Test method DataAccessTest.RequirementUnitTest+DeleteRequirement.DeleteRequirementSuccessfully threw exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string named
    'RequirementsDatabaseEntities' could be found in the application config file.
```

If I comment out `the context.VerifyGet` line the test passes, but the
requirement is not deleted from the list. Does anyone have any idea why?

1. The test fails
2. And why when I comment out the offending line, it passes but the requirement
   has not been deleted.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Looks like you're somehow touching database with your unit test, which you DO NOT want to do - unit tests should be carried out in isolation - otherwise they become integration tests. What is RequirementsDatabaseEntities?

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but cannot figure out why it is happening. Also I don't know why the entity is not being removed.

Comment: RequirementsDatabaseEntities is the DbContext

Comment: Ok, do how you like. This error probably tells you that EF cannot find connection string named RequirementsDatabaseEntities in Web.config file. Make sure you have line like <add name="RequirementsDatabaseEntities " connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> in Web.config. Also modify your RequirementsDatabaseEntities constructor to look like public RequirementsDatabaseEntities ()
            : base("aspnetdb")           
        {
        }

Comment: Where aspnetdb is your db name, make sure it's the same in constructor and connection string

Comment: OK Thanks, but I am trying to unit test without the database. Does anyone know why the database is not being mocked out

Comment: perhaps you should expose your requirementdatabaseentities via some interface instead. Then you can mock the interface.

Answer (score 6):

First edit your definition of `requirements` to be a `List<Requirement>` not a `Queryable` to be able to mocking add or remove. And use `requirements.AsQueryable()` in `Setup` methods.

Second add this code to mocking remove:

```
mockDbSet.Setup(m => m.Remove(It.IsAny<Requirement>())).Callback<Requirement>((entity) => requirements.Remove(entity));
```

So you can check the count of your `requirements` list after removing.
Your code should be like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeleteRequirementSuccessfully()
{
    var requirements = new List<Requirement>
    {
        new Requirement {
            Id = 1,
            Title = "Requirement 1",
            Description = "Requirement 1 description"
        },
        new Requirement {
            Id = 2,
            Title = "Requirement 2",
            Description = "Requirement 2 description"
        },
        new Requirement {
            Id = 3,
            Title = "Requirement 3",
            Description = "Requirement 3 description"
        }
    };

    var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Requirement>>();
    var context = new Mock<RequirementsDatabaseEntities>();

    // You should use .AsQueryable() in these lines
    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Requirement>>()
             .Setup(x => x.Provider)
             .Returns(requirements.AsQueryable().Provider);
    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Requirement>>()
             .Setup(x => x.ElementType)
             .Returns(requirements.AsQueryable().ElementType);
    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Requirement>>()
             .Setup(x => x.Expression)
             .Returns(requirements.AsQueryable().Expression);
    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Requirement>>()
             .Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator())
             .Returns(requirements.GetEnumerator());

    // This line should be added
    mockDbSet.Setup(m => m.Remove(It.IsAny<Requirement>())).Callback<Requirement>((entity) => requirements.Remove(entity));

    context.Setup(x => x.Requirement).Returns(mockDbSet.Object);

    var dataAccess = new RequirementsDataAccess(context.Object);
    int idToDelete = 1;
    dataAccess.DeleteRequirement(idToDelete);

    context.VerifyGet(x => x.Requirement, Times.Exactly(2));
    //mockDbSet.Verify(x => x.Remove(It.IsAny<Requirement>()), Times.Once());
    context.Verify(x => x.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());

    // add this Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(requirement.Count, 2);
    // or
    Assert.IsFalse(requirement.Any(x => x.Id == idToDelete));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. it fails because you can't mock non virtual method.
2. the same problem: `RequirementsDatabaseEntities.Requirement` is not virtual method than it provide different output in test method than you expected. it probably returns empty collection.

fix: make `RequirementsDatabaseEntities.Requirement` getter virtual

Comment: In the link it sets up this method to be virtual. I think when using VS2013 EF 6.1 this is the default code generation template. Also would I not get an compile time error?

Comment: You have to check your generated code. There is more than one approach how to generate code and it should differ: Legacy, T4, Code First and maybe more. You don't get an error because mock type is constructed in runtime than compiler don't complain. Suppose new type only hide original non virtual method as you can do this as well in your inheritance. This is why I suppose your test method offer real property instead.

Comment: I just checked, and it is virtual. The strange thing is that when I debug the test and the context.Requirement is called it does rerun the mocked DbContext (RequirementsDatabaseEntities). It's very strange.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Solution -** I found that the exception was just misleading. It was giving me this exception as I had got the number of times the mocked property was called wrong. It should have been called twice, instead of once. That part works now. But I still do not understand why the entity is not being removed from the list. Is it because it is queryable?

Answer (score 0):

Since Moq uses inheritance in order to replace method calls you can only mock virtual methods (or interfaces).

So either make the methods/properties you're trying to fake virtual or use Isolator/JustMock etc. that work using Jit weaving and can fake these methods.

Comment: jit.. weaving.. that sounds interesting. Do you have any links/documentation that describes it? My initial google search is a bit scarce (it shows aspect-weaving and run-time weaving.. not sure if that is the same?)

Comment: #Default: If you're interested in these tools the .NET space has three at the moment: Typemock Isolator, Telerik's JustMock and MS Fakes (with VS2012/2013). All of these use the .NET profiler API to inject code during runtime which enables faking of virtually anything you want

Comment: In the link it sets up this method to be virtual. I think when using VS2013 EF 6.1 this is the default code generation template. Also would I not get an compile time error?